# Question about proof of Picard's Great Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $R > 0, a \in \mathbb{C}, D_R^* = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < |z-a|<R\}$. Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $D_R^*$ and suppose that $f$ has an essential singularity at $a$. Then $f(D_R^*)$ contains every complex number with at most one exception.

From Raghavan Narasimhan's Complex Analysis in One Variable:

> Proof: If $\alpha, \beta \notin f(D_R^*)$ then $0,1 \notin g(D_R^*)$, where $g = (\beta - \alpha)^{-1}(f-\alpha)$; clearly $g$ is holomorphic on $D_R^*$ and has an essential singularity at $a$ if f does. By the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem, there is a sequence $\{z_n\}$ of complex numbers such that $z_n \to 0, |z_{n+1}| < |z_n| < Re^{-2\pi}$ for $n \geq 1$, and such that $|g(a+z_n)| < 1$.

My question is: How I construct the sequence $\{z_n\}$? I don't understand how it results this from Casorati-Weierstrass theorem. Thanks!

Comment: Weierstrass-Casorati says that the function get arbitrarily close to any given number on any neighbourhood of the essential singularity.  Now you only want $a+z_{n+1}$ in the small disc $D(a,\lvert z_n\rvert)$ with $g(a+z_n)$ close to $0$.